# key enter event in a text box

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am using the new Microsoft visual studio 2012 express for Windows 8 C++ + DirectX
and i want to recognize if the key <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed while the textbox got focus.
So i did a key_down event for the text box but now i dont know how to recognize if the key is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

```
void App1::MainPage::input_KeyDown(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
     //Recognize enter key
}
```

I have been looking for a solution but all use e->KeyCode but this methods doesn't exist in Microsoft visual studio 2012 express for Windows 8 C++ so what i have to do ??
Sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it works in C++. But in C# I would do that:

```
if (e.Key.Equals(VirtualKey.Enter)
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried something like this:
if(e->Key == VirtualKey::Enter)
{}
(i found it on internet) but it doesnt recognize VirtualKey do i have to add something ??

Comment: i have looked to the page VirtualKey and to requirments it says that he needs namespace -> Windows::System
And metadata ->  Windows.winmd 
How can i add this metadata ? is this the problem why VirtualKey isn't recognized ? Because i copied my code from Microsoft site, in fact he gives error only on VirtualKey.

Comment: You could try to use the `int` value directly  

 `if(e->Key == 13)`

(source: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1))

Comment: @Marco, you can either use "using Windows.System;" or just Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter